# miktex strange error

Tags: miktex, windows

I'm using Miktex with Texstudio on Windows 10.
Suddenly without any changes or settings changed, MiKTeX started throwing errors when new packages were requested. 
Texstudio simply says:

```
Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ThesisReport".tex

Unfortunately, the package breqn could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\xelatex.log
```

When starting the MiKTeX console, I receive a waning notification from windows. When trying to choose the option "stay in user mode" in the MiKTeX console, I received following error message:

```
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
Date: 2020-02-12 22:11:22
MiKTeX: 2.9.7250
OS: Windows 10 Education, 64-bit, build 18363
SharedSetup: yes
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: 2020-01-31 15:55:58
LastUpdateAdmin: 2020-01-31 14:51:12
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Karl\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: non-existing/explorer

ERROR DETAILS
Program: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console.exe
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Cfg\Cfg.cpp:1052
Error: A MiKTeX configuration file could not be loaded.
Details: 
  file: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini
  line: 89804
  error: invalid value definition
```

Line 89804 contains: `nual4.html`

These are the surrounding lines:
[image]

I have no idea, what happened. 
Maybe someone can give me an idea, where the error sits?

Comment: Ok, apparently I could make a dirty fix.
I replaced the line in question with:
`doc[]=texmf/doc/latex/hyperref/manual4.html`
This lets me call miktex console without error again, and gets rid of the errors thrown at startup of miktex console

Comment: This edit got the whole MiKTeX running again. it can install new packages now.
But seriously - what went wrong here?
I'm apparently also missing some lines in that file. 
Could someone send me the lines in question from their miktex installation?